# Plot GLM model in R

Tags: r

I am doing a linear regression model, so right now I have

```
mylogit <- glm(Gender ~ Drug*Environment + Ethnicity + Age, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
```

Gender (F/M), Drug (Y/N), Environment (H/L) are all factors and age is the only numeric.

I am trying to graph a scatter plot with proportion of males (y-axis) vs. age (x-axis). There are four conditions, so four different colors/lines:

1) Drug Y/Env H
2) Drug N/Env H
3) Drug N/Env L
4) Drug Y/Env L

I've tried using

```
plot(effect("Gender*Drug*Environment*Age", mylogit, xlevels=list(Age=20:60)), + multiline=TRUE, rug=FALSE)
```

But this just separates it into two graphs with two lines in each graph and does not plot the individual data points on there.

Comment: Just to be clear here, `Gender` is your target variable? I don't use `glm` much so I could be missing something.

Comment: Yes, Gender would be the dependent variable.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of this untested code. (Provide data if you want tested code.)

```
plot(x=seq(20, 65, by=5), predict( mlogit, 
                    newdata=data.frame(Drug="Y", Environment="H", Ethnicity="White",
                   Age=seq(20, 65, by=5) ), type="response" ) )
lines(x=seq(20, 65, by=5), predict( mlogit, 
                   newdata=data.frame(Drug="N", Environment="L", Ethnicity="White",
                   Age=seq(20, 65, by=5) ), type="response" ) )
```

You can add the other groups as needed and note that predict.glm will need valid values for the Ethnicity variable.

Comment: Hmm so for example if these are the data (and forget Ethnicity). Ahh sorry I can't figure out how to <br\> these!
    Gender=(M, M, F, M, F, F, F, M, F, M) 
    Drug=(Y, Y, Y, Y, Y, N, N, N, N, N)
    Environment = (H, L, H, L, H, L, L, L, H, H)
    Age= (20, 33, 55, 45, 46, 47, 23, 31, 43, 38)

Comment: You should post as an edit, rather than as a comment, the results of dput(mydata). The vectors above are not R code and do not have Ethnicity.